# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What I want to do:**

I want to print a filename. I could see the output file is available. But I'm unable to print the filename alone.

**Python code:**

```
today=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
string_file="string_"+today+".csv"
outputFile = open(string_file_rdkb, "w")
#....some code here...
my_df=pd.DataFrame(datalist2)
my_df.to_csv(outputFile, index=False, header=False)
print(outputFile + " is generated") #Here is the issue
```

**Output shows:**

```
print(outputFile + " is generated")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str'
```

**What I tried to solve:**

```
print(str(outputFile) + " is generated")
```

**Output Shows:**

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='string_20181213-160004.csv' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'> is generated
```

**Expected Output:**

```
string_20181213-160004.csv is generated
```

Comment: I think you want to print the variable `string_file` which is a string, and not `outputFile` which is an open file object.

Comment: What about printing the file **name** `string_file` instead of the file object?

Comment: I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use : `print(outputFile.name + " is generated")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the variable `string_file` that you've defined, as this is just the name of the file already in a string format;

```
today=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
string_file="string_"+today+".csv"
outputFile = open(string_file_rdkb, "w")
#....some code here...
my_df=pd.DataFrame(datalist2)
my_df.to_csv(outputFile, index=False, header=False)
print(string_file+ " is generated") #Here is the issue
```

Output:

```
>>> string_20181213-160004.csv is generated
```

What you were printing before is the file `object` that is a result of calling `open()` on the file name, hence it's returning the object itself as opposed to just the name.

Comment: why use a self created variable when `io.TextIOWrapper` has a property that represent exactly that.

Comment: Because the variable is already created to be used in the assignation to `outputFile`. Either way is acceptable and in fact this form is more legible.

Comment: I know , but using the object prop is more straight forward